# Laravel artisan not doing anything

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to get started with Laravel. I have installed Laravel using composer, now I am trying to create my first project. All went fine uptil I tried to generate my first DB migration, when I am getting no output from:

```
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]# php artisan make:migration create_customers_table --create=customers
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]# php artisan list
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]#
```

Has anybody ever experienced similar issue? Project creation with laravel new went just fine. I modified .env, config/app.php and config/database.php, nothing else. I am currently runnig v5.2.14 of Laravel framework.

## Update 1

I have checked .env and I have APP_DEBUG=true configured, when I list files in storage/logs, there are not logfiles.

```
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]# ll storage/logs/
total 0
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]#
```

Comment: is APP_DEBUG set to true in your .env? did you check storage/logs/laravel.log (or lumen.log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered I had too old version of PHP 5 for Laravel, I have performed an PHP upgrade to:

```
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]# php --version
PHP 5.5.31 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2016 10:01:20) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
[root@glczwe-sp230001 my.perlur.cz]#
```

And it started to work after running composer install to get all the dependencies.